# Updating child entities ABP

Tags: entity-framework-core, aspnetboilerplate

I'm trying to work with child entities in `ABP` but when I call repository methods nothing happens, the way i'm doing it is deleting all records and Inserting it again, when methods are called I got duplicate entries

I'm working with it in `DomainService` layer here is my manager

```
    using Abp.Domain.Repositories;
    using Abp.Domain.Services;
    using DomiSys.Prestamos.Models.Generales.ClienteFuturoNs.DireccionClienteFuturoNs;
    using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;

    namespace DomiSys.Prestamos.Models.Generales.DireccionClienteFuturoNs
    {
        public class DireccionClienteFuturoManager : DomainService, IDireccionClienteFuturoManager
        {
            private readonly IRepository<DireccionClienteFuturo> _direccionClienteFuturoRepository;

            public DireccionClienteFuturoManager(IRepository<DireccionClienteFuturo> direccionClienteFuturoRepository)
            {
                LocalizationSourceName = PrestamosConsts.LocalizationSourceName;
                _direccionClienteFuturoRepository = direccionClienteFuturoRepository;
            }


            public async Task<DireccionClienteFuturo> Registrar(DireccionClienteFuturo entity)
            {
                return await _direccionClienteFuturoRepository.InsertAsync(entity);
            }

            public async void Eliminar(DireccionClienteFuturo entity)
            {
                await _direccionClienteFuturoRepository.DeleteAsync(entity);
            }

            public async void EliminarTodo(int clienteId)
            {
                var list = _direccionClienteFuturoRepository.GetAll().Where(x => x.ClienteFuturoId == clienteId).ToList();
                foreach (var item in list)
                {
                    await _direccionClienteFuturoRepository.DeleteAsync(item);
                }
            }

            public async void RegistrarLista(IEnumerable<DireccionClienteFuturo> lista)
            {
                foreach (var item in lista)
                {
                    item.Id = 0;
                    await _direccionClienteFuturoRepository.InsertAsync(item);
                }
            }

        }
    }
```

And I'm using it like this

```
    private void InsertarDireccion(ClienteFuturo clienteNuevo)
    {
        _direccionClienteFuturoManager.EliminarTodo(clienteNuevo.Id);
        _direccionClienteFuturoManager.RegistrarLista(clienteNuevo.ListaDirecciones);
    }


    public Task<ClienteFuturo> Actualizar(ClienteFuturo entity)
    {

        Validar(entity);
        entity.SucursalId = usuario.SucursalId ?? 0;

        InsertaActualizaConyugue(entity);

        entity.FechaNacimiento = Shared.Shared.FormateaFecha(entity.FechaNacimiento);
        var result = _clienteRepository.Update(entity);

        InsertarTelefono(entity);
        InsertarEmail(entity);
        InsertarDireccion(entity);


        return Task.FromResult(result);
    }
```

`InsertaTelefonos(entity)` method is called from `Actualizar` method

When methods are called I got duplicate entries in database.

What I'm doing wrong ?

Comment: [AutoMapper.Collection.EFCore](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper.Collection.EFCore)

Comment: Do you have an example I can use?, or can Make one based on my code?

Comment: Okay bro, no problem, be sure that’s not my wish you code for me, I just said it thinking you have an example in some code in a project you have participate it or developed, but don’t worry I will check for it, thanks.

Comment: Can you describe better the issue? What is not working? There's several methods and it's not clear which is failing or what is your desired result. But I have a hunch: How is `ClienteFuturo entity` passed in? Is it loaded previously from the db? You might need to understand how to work with EF in a disconnected scenario. Also, to modify child entities, you need to load them first.